# iText - PdfAnnotation.createInk

Tags: itext

I am trying to parse annotation data in XFDF and draw it using the iText Library. I want to draw the annotation like the attached image.

Following is my code to test the PdfAnnotation.createInk function, but it is not working after run the code.

I have Google and read the documents, but not much information provided. Any suggestions and advice? Thanks!

```
// step 1
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(destFile));
    // step 3
    document.open();

    PdfContentByte pcb = new PdfContentByte(writer);
    pcb.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(52.92f, 397.56f, 173.36f, 530.67f);
    float[][] inkList = {{61.736111f,530.669250f},{61.295139f,525.820984f},{61.295139f,518.768860f},
            {61.295139f,505.986969f},{61.295139f,490.560547f},{61.295139f,470.726562f},{59.972221f,452.214844f},
            {57.767361f,434.143890f},{56.003471f,418.276703f},{53.357639f,404.172516f},{51.593750f,391.390625f},
            {50.711807f,382.134766f},{49.829861f,376.845703f}
    };

    //float inkList[][] =
    PdfAnnotation an = PdfAnnotation.createInk(writer, rect, "", inkList);
    an.setPage(1);
    an.setColor(BaseColor.RED);
    an.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);

    writer.addAnnotation(an);
    //Step 5
    document.close();
```

[image]

Comment: *but it is not working* - what happens instead?

Comment: Output the pdf without any annotations

Comment: I won't be in office anymore this week. If your question isn't answered by the start of next week, I'll look into it then.

Comment: Thanks do you have any references that show how to use PdfAnnotation.createInk function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output PDF seemingly does not contain an annotation because the defined annotation is a mere collection of isolated points.

The `float[][]` parameter of `PdfAnnotation.createInk` corresponds to the **InkList** entry of the  **Ink** annotation dictionary:

> **InkList** array *(Required)* An array of n arrays, each representing a stroked path. Each
>   array shall be a series of alternating horizontal and vertical coordinates in
>   default user space, specifying points along the path. When drawn, the
>   points shall be connected by straight lines or curves in an
>   implementation-dependent way.

Thus, in case of the OPs array

```
float[][] inkList = {{61.736111f,530.669250f},{61.295139f,525.820984f},{61.295139f,518.768860f},
        {61.295139f,505.986969f},{61.295139f,490.560547f},{61.295139f,470.726562f},{59.972221f,452.214844f},
        {57.767361f,434.143890f},{56.003471f,418.276703f},{53.357639f,404.172516f},{51.593750f,391.390625f},
        {50.711807f,382.134766f},{49.829861f,376.845703f}
};
```

we have a collection of 13 paths each of which contain only a single point. So, nothing is drawn.

If we combine all the points in a single path, though,

```
    float[][] inkList = {{61.736111f,530.669250f,61.295139f,525.820984f,61.295139f,518.768860f,
            61.295139f,505.986969f,61.295139f,490.560547f,61.295139f,470.726562f,59.972221f,452.214844f,
            57.767361f,434.143890f,56.003471f,418.276703f,53.357639f,404.172516f,51.593750f,391.390625f,
            50.711807f,382.134766f,49.829861f,376.845703f}
    };
```

the result is this:

[image: Screenshot]

which looks like the left line of the "H" in the screenshot in the question.

Comment: Besides, do you know how to set the line width for the annotation? Thanks.

Comment: Cf. [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27501490/1729265) to your [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27497333/1729265).