# iTextSharp: annotations not displaying in some PDF viewing applications

Tags: unity-game-engine, itext

I am using iTextSharp to write annotations to pdf files-- at this point, just graphical annotations (lines and rectangles).  The problem I'm having is that the annotations I'm creating are not visible in some external applications I'm using to view PDFs.  The annotations do show up correctly in Adobe Reader and in Goodreader for IOS;  they don't appear in Preview for OSX or in the application I'm writing in Unity, which uses an asset called PDFRenderer to generate textures from PDF pages.  I had thought that maybe the problem was that PDFRenderer was not displaying all layers in the PDF documents.  But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187208/itextsharp-createink-method-curves-and-corners) to a different question of mine suggests that creating a PDFAppearance might solve the problem.  I'm now trying to figure out how to do that, but the documentation I've been able to find hasn't been much help.  If anyone could point me towards a good example, or good documentation, I'd be grateful.  Likewise, if you know that the issue isn't with PdfApperances, please let me know that. Thanks.

Comment: You literally ignored that answer only to ask a new one. You can comment under that answer and ask for more clarification from the person that provided that answer. That answer can also be [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it solved your problem.

Comment: iText is following the PDF specification. In the PDF specification, you can choose whether or not you define an appearance. If you don't define an appearance, that appearance is created by the PDF viewer. Unfortunately, not every PDF viewer implements the full PDF specification: some viewers completely ignore annotations for which no appearance is defined. In that case, you should use iText to create the appearance as explained in the answer by @mkl but be aware that some PDF viewers completely ignore *all* annotations, even those for which an appearance exists. Don't use such viewers.

Comment: Well, there are two different problems: the first is about drawing annotation rectangles with corners, the second about creating appearances for annotations so that external applications can view them.  @mkl's answer solved the first problem by recommending the CreatePolygonPolyline method.  That doesn't solve the second problem,  though.  Thought I was being helpful in asking the second question separately so that others with the second problem might be able to find it more easily.  I'll ask for clarification on the other thread as you suggest.  Thanks.